# Extend Vim's Perl folding on 'sub' to include 'func' and 'method' from Method::Signatures

Tags: perl, vim

I like to use vim's fold feature, but when using the Perl module Method::Signatures I lose the benefit of folding in Perl code on subroutines. I looked in perl.vim to see if I could extend the folding on not just sub's but also func's and method's. Has anyone had any luck doing this? I only managed to break things. I did install https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl and enable syntax high-lighting on those two tags, but that was fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work well:

```
" Installation: Put into after/syntax/perl/method-signatures.vim

syn match perlFunction +\<method\>\_s*+ nextgroup=perlSubName
syn match perlFunction +\<func\>\_s*+ nextgroup=perlSubName

if get(g:, 'perl_fold', 0)
        syn region perlSubFold     start="\<method\>[^;]*{" end="}" transparent fold extend
        syn region perlSubFold     start="\<func\>[^;]*{" end="}" transparent fold extend
else
        syn region perlSubFold     start="^\z(\s*\)\<method\>.*[^};]$" end="^\z1}\s*\%(#.*\)\=$" fold transparent
        syn region perlSubFold     start="^\z(\s*\)\<func\>.*[^};]$" end="^\z1}\s*\%(#.*\)\=$" fold transparent
endif
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/blob/dev/contrib/method-signatures.vim